# How to grant users read-only access to all databases

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want a group of users to have read-only access to all tables and views on all databases on SQL Server (I'm using SS2008). I'd like those users to have read-only access to all future tables and view.

How would you set that up?

Comment: Since this is a really old question that still gets a lot of views, be aware that in SQL 2014+, `GRANT CONNECT ANY DATABASE TO <SQL_Login>;` along with `GRANT SELECT ALL USER SECURABLES TO <SQL_Login>;` is going to be much easier than the old way of doing things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add the user to the `db_datareader` role

example

```
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader',YourLogin
```

Info about `db_datareader`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188629(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: This gives read-only access to a single database, not to all databases. You will have to do this for each database.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR

LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT name FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases OPEN db_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    /* This sentence will be executed to gran the privileges. */
    SELECT @statement = 'use ['+@dbname+']; '+'EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_datareader'', N''userPeter''';
    EXEC sp_executesql @statement
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname
END
```

In the location that appear `userPeter` you must write your username.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add the users to the db_datareader database role in each of the databases. You could write a script to loop through the databases and do it for you.