# Read Account SQL Server without them seeing other DB's

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've searched a lot on the internet and StackOverflow but there is none that could give me the answer.

I would like to create a SQL Server account with the following options:

1. ReadOnly for one database
2. They can only see the designated database

And yes I've seen the option where you can remove the public and make them owner but that isn't an option because they aren't allowed to write or create in the database.

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: THis should get you started, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196502/how-to-grant-users-read-only-access-to-all-databases Just add the role in the db they are meant to have...

Comment: Thx!, but the readonly alone wasn't the problem, it's the combination whats the problem

Comment: When you say "see" do you want them to see that database within SSMS?  Or just be able to query the one database?

Comment: combination of what? they can see other dbms???

Comment: They may only see and query the one database that i want them to work with. 
It's like this, I don't want them to see my other customers databases.

Comment: If you want them to only see 1 db in SSMS, they answer is no, it's not possible.  If you DENY "View any database", then they are unable to see ALL databases.  But given the correct permissions, they could write a query and execute it against the one database, though they can't see it in SSMS.

Comment: @Dbloch Thanks for the help, accidentally cancelled the upvote so upvoted your other comment.